# MOOC Helsinki week 10 exercise 28 weird test results

Tags: java

Short version:

Why this code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for (Movable i : this.allObjects) {
        result += i.toString();
        result +='\n';
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is accepted by autmatic tests while not producing results on my console, while this one:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    for (Movable i : this.allObjects) {
        System.out.println(i.toString());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Prints propers results on my console while printing nothing according to the same tests?

Long version:

I'm learning Java with MOOC created by University of Helsinki and I'm really surprised with outcome of one of the exercises. It's here:

http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part2/material/week-10?noredirect=1

number 28. It's pretty straightforward and plain exercise about object polymorphism and I wrote a code that was consistently giving expected outcome in the console. But here's catch. I wasn't able to pass tests. The errors I was recieving looked like I was unable to print results, despite the fact that I was seeing those results on my screen. I managed to pinpoint the place where the mistake is to overridden toString method from Group class

I spent some time trying to find mistake in my code, to no avail. So finally I gave up and - first time since I started this course - I searched for a right answer. When I applied found solution the tests were passed BUT iI couldn't see any results on my console. And I have no idea why.

Comment: This is almost a cross-site duplicate of [Teaching students that printf() is not the same as return](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/teaching-students-that-printf-is-not-the-same-as-return) over at CS Educators.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not supposed to see anything on the console. The `toString()` method **returns** a `String` representation of the object. In the correct code, a proper result is returned.

In your code, you're explicitly printing things on the console, then returning an empty `String`.

Comment: All right, I think I know where my mistake was! I was thinking that toString methog is a way to print objects, but in reality it's a way to present them as Strings and them maybe, but not necessarily print. Thanks for an answer!

Comment: Indeed. After all, you don't know where to print it. Your code assumes that the console is always available, when that might not be true.